# Howto add my own item to the Menu/Wallpaper?

Tags: android

I noticed that some android applications are adding its own menu item to the "Select wallpaper from" menu. Please how can I add my own item to the menu?
The menu is accessible from home screen by clicking to menu and clicking to the Walpaper item.

Answer (score 1):

You create you own [live wallpaper](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/02/live-wallpapers.html).

Comment: I have created my own live wallpaper, but it appears in the menu only on the Samsung Gallaxy S. Not on other devices.

Comment: Live wallpapers are for Android 2.1 and above. Check that your devices have appropriate versions.